# Induction of a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I need to prove using induction
$$1 \cdot n + 2(n-1)+3(n-2)+ \cdots +n \cdot 1 = {n \over 6}(n+1)(n+2)$$

but when I put $n=k+1$ I get:
$$1 \cdot (k+1) + 2(k)+3(k-1)+ \cdots +k \cdot 2+ (k+1) \cdot 1 = {k+1 \over 6}(k+2)(k+3)$$

and I have no idea how to procceed. :(

Thank for anyone who can help!

Comment: You need to use the inductive hypothesis. Do you know what that is?

Comment: I do, but when when n=k+1 I don't see how can I use it

Answer (score 0):

I'm only writing the inductive step as you should be able to fill in the rest.
$$1 \cdot (k+1) + 2(k)+3(k-1)+ \cdots +k \cdot 2+ (k+1) \cdot 1\\
=1 \cdot (k+1)+k+(k-1)+\cdots+2+1+{k \over 6}(k+1)(k+2)\\
= {(k+1)(k+2) \over 2}+{k \over 6}(k+1)(k+2)\\
= {3(k+1)(k+2)+k(k+1)(k+2)\over 6}\\
={k+1 \over 6}(k+2)(k+3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing $n$ from $k$ to $k+1$ increases the $i$th of the original $k$ terms by $i$; we also add an extra term equal to $k+1$. The result is$$\begin{align}\tfrac16k(k+1)(k+2)+\tfrac12k(k+1)+k+1&=\tfrac16(k+1)(k^2+2k+3k+6)\\&=\tfrac16(k+1)(k+2)(k+3).\end{align}$$